# reuse code in flask blueprints

Tags: python, rest, flask

I have a REST api implemented in flask. now we are exposing a set of tables as resources...so I have 2 new resources `res1` and `res2` manipulating the corresponding table in the backend. I wanted to find out how best to reuse code.

I was thinking of using a common blueprint `common_bp`, so i can register it as

```
app.register_blueprint(common_bp, url_prefix='/res1')
app.register_blueprint(common_bp, url_prefix='/res2')...
```

Have a couple of questions:

Is this the right way to do it?

If so, how do i know inside common_bp which `res1` or `res2` it got called for?

Thanks

Comment: I found that many StackOverflow pages and other sites have solutions demanding the use of a blueprint. It's not necessary. A regular Python module will do.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to say that if the resources are similar enough to be handled by the same blueprint, you can probably create a blueprint generic enough that will handle both ressources.

On top of that, it seems like registering the same blueprint multiple times will put you in weird situations like [this issue](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/1091).